# Laravel: How to search DB for a given string using eloquent?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I would like to retrieve data matching the search string, provided, it must not belongs to current user.

```
if($str_search && $str_search != '' )
{
  $mandate_list = Mandate::select(array('umrn','mandate_status', 'payment_type','currency','fixed_amount','max_amount','user_id','id','debtor_bank','creditor_bank','refusal_reason'))
                        ->orWhere('id', 'LIKE', '%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('umrn','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('mandate_status','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('mandate_date','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('payment_type','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('currency','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('fixed_amount','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')
                        ->orWhere('mandate_date','LIKE','%'.$str_search.'%')   
                        ->where('user_id', '<>', $current_user) 
                        ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')                            
                        ->get();

}
```

But this query displays all records (even belongs to current user).
How can i solve this. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group all your `orWhere`s in a closure:

```php
Mandate::select([.....])->where(function($query) use ($str_search)
{
    $columns = ['id', 'umrn', 'mandate_status', ...];

    foreach ($columns as $column)
    {
        $query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', '%'.$str_search.'%');
    }
})
->where('user_id', '<>', $current_user) 
->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')                            
->get();
```

Comment: When I implement this code I am getting `{"error":{"type":"ErrorException","message":"Undefined variable: str_search","file"` in `foreach` .

Comment: You can pass the $str_search variable to the function callback using `use`:
`[....]->where(function($query) use ($str_search) {[.....]});`

Comment: @NithilGeorge - updated the answer to `use` your `$str_search` variable.